# Assign a list of char *

Tags: char

Explain in a simple example. How to pass a `char*` to a function?

```
#define name1 "ABCD"
#define name2 "EFGH"
#define name3 "HIJK"

char *list[3] = {};

void printList(char *l, int x) {
  for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    Serial.println(l[i]);
  }

}



void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("start");
  list[0] = name1;
  list[1] = name2;
  list[2] = name3;

  printList(list, 3);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

I get an error:

```
/home/guy/Documents/Dropbox/Arduino/sketch_jun12a/sketch_jun12a.ino: In function 'void setup()':
sketch_jun12a:24:13: error: cannot convert 'char**' to 'char*'
   24 |   printList(list, 3);
      |             ^~~~
      |             |
      |             char**
/home/guy/Documents/Dropbox/Arduino/sketch_jun12a/sketch_jun12a.ino:7:22: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void printList(char*, int)'
    7 | void printList(char *l, int x) {
      |                ~~~~~~^
exit status 1
cannot convert 'char**' to 'char*'
```

Comment: You're trying to pass an array of char * to a function that is expecting a single char *.

Comment: @Majenko AFAIK anyway you pass only  pointer for the first cell of the array,  or am I wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change this:

```cpp
void printList(char *l, int x) {
```

to this:

```cpp
void printList(char **l, int x) {
```

OK, this deserves some explanation...

In C and C++, when you **use** (not when you *define*) an array
identifier, it [decays to a pointer to its first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay). In
this case,

```cpp
char *list[3] = {};
```

is an array of pointers to `char`. When you use it here:

```cpp
printList(list, 3);
```

it decays to a pointer to pointer to `char`. Thus the double `*` needed
in the parameter declaration.

**Side note**: to get really correct C++, you should replace every
instance of `char` by `const char`. This is because the characters in
question belong to string literals, and you are not allowed to modify a
string literal at run time.